# Is access to the Java Heap restricted to the JVM which runs the program

Tags: java, jvm

Assume  I  have  2 instances of  Java installed in a  Linux machine: A JRE and a JDK.
If I run a java `program1.java`  with  a JRE, and then use the different JDK to get a  Heap dump of `program1.java` using `jmap`, why does it return data?

Should not the heap be accessible only by the JVM which initiated the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second program does not do the work needed to generate the heap dump.  It merely tells the first JVM to do it.  The mechanism is platform dependent but on Linux it is done by sending a suitable signal.

Note that for Java 6 there is a new possibility in the Attach API which allows the second Java program to interact much more with the first JVM, but still under the control of the first JVM.

Answer (score 1):

The `jmap` process attaches to the running JVM process and produces the mapping using debugging APIs.  This happens regardless of where `jmap` is installed, in JRE or JDK directories or anywhere else.

Comment: You can trigger a heap dump even if the JVM is not started in debugging mode.